# Как понять к какому элементу списка относиться выбраный элемент ComboBox в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть модель

```
    public class UCClipProcessingModel : BaseModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ClipProcessingGridItem> GridItems { get; }
                = new ObservableCollection<ClipProcessingGridItem>();
    }
```

вот так выглядит `ClipProcessingGridItem`

```
    public class ClipProcessingGridItem: IValidable
    {
        public MCClipFolder ClipFolder { get; set; }

        public MCGeoCalibFolder SelectedGeoCalibrationFolder { get; set; } = MCGeoCalibFolder.EMPTY();

        public ObservableCollection<MCGeoCalibFolder> GeoCalibrationFolders { get; set; }
                = new ObservableCollection<MCGeoCalibFolder>();

        public MCColorCalibFolder SelectedColorCalibrationFolder { get; set; } = MCColorCalibFolder.EMPTY();

        public ObservableCollection<MCColorCalibFolder> ColorCalibrationFolders { get; set; }
                = new ObservableCollection<MCColorCalibFolder>();

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

В `.xalm` как контекст я использую `UCClipProcessingModel` и для `DataGrid` используются `GridItems` и каждый элемент этой колекции это по сути ряд в `DataGrid`

В ряду у меня есть `DataGridTemplateColumn`

```
...
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Geometry calibration folder">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="Cb_geometry_calibration"
                                                      SelectionChanged="Cb_geometry_calibration_SelectionChanged"
                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GeoCalibrationFolders}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGeoCalibrationFolder}">
                                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UIRepresentation}" />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

Вот скриншот для наглядности

[image]

Теперь когда юзер выбирает, что то в этом `ComboBox` мне нужно знать, что он выбрал. Для этого я установил `SelectionChanged`

```
        private void Cb_geometry_calibration_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem) is MCGeoCalibFolder itemm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item clicked: {itemm.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

И вроде бы все работает и я получаю актуальное значение в слушателе, но проблема в том, что я не знаю к какому `ClipProcessingGridItem` из `ObservableCollection` это значение относиться

**Вопрос - ** Как узнать к какому элементу относиться значение?

Comment: Посмотрите под отладчиком в свойство DataContext контрола

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам примерчик
[image: пример работы]

Классы модели

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Вьюмодель основного окна

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    //ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //>>>>>Заполняем данными
        Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>
        {
            new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Жигули" },
            new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Волга" },
            new Car { Id = 3, Name = "УАЗ" },
        };

        var drivers = new List<Driver>
        {
            new Driver { Id = 1, FIO = "Иванов Ф.С.", Car = Cars[0] },
            new Driver { Id = 2, FIO = "Сергеев А.Д.", Car = Cars[2] },
            new Driver { Id = 3, FIO = "Петров Е.Д.", Car = Cars[1] },
        };

        Drivers = new ObservableCollection<DriverViewModel>();
        drivers.ForEach(d => Drivers.Add(new DriverViewModel(d)));
        //<<<<<Заполняем данными
    }

    //водители
    public ObservableCollection<DriverViewModel> Drivers { get; }
    //выбранный в datagrid водитель
    public DriverViewModel CurrentDriver { get; set; }
    //автомобили для combobox
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; }

    //выбранный в комбобокс автомобиль
    public Car CurrentCar
    {
        set
        {
            //изменяем у выбранного водителя автомобиль
            CurrentDriver.Car = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Для водителя придется создать свою вьюмодель, т.к. нам нужно реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged` с тем чтоб отобразить изменения в DataGrid

```
public class DriverViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Driver _driver;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DriverViewModel(Driver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public string FIO => _driver.FIO;

    //авто
    public Car Car
    {
        get => _driver.Car;
        set
        { 
            _driver.Car = value;
            //сообщаем об изменении авто, чтоб отобразить в datagrid
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Car)));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML окна

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp3.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WpfApp3" Height="313.126" Width="674.376" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Canvas>
    <DataGrid Height="248"
              Canvas.Left="19"
              Canvas.Top="10"
              Width="639"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource ="{Binding Drivers}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDriver}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150"
                                Header="Водитель"
                                Binding="{Binding FIO}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150"
                                Header="Автомобиль"
                                Binding="{Binding Car.Name}"
                                 />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Автомобили"
                                    MinWidth="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCar}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Canvas>
```

Comment: Я вот только хотел уточнить, а как тут поступить с вашим примером если допустим `ObservableCollection Cars` заполнялся бы не в конструкторе хардкодно, а допустим чтением из файла. То есть мне нужно как то сначала прочитать файл, потом как то передать значение во вью модель. Но ведь она уже создана в `.xalm` как то не удобно получается

Comment: В конструкторе коллекцию машин можно создать пустой, а затем в отдельном методе заполнить коллекцию данными. Если вы используете `ObservableCollection` `Add()` вы оповестите вьюху о появлении новых данных в этой коллекции.